# How to match a set of strings spread across two lines?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a file that may contain the following block of code in any one of the combinations. I need to check for the presence of "import telemetry" in the file.

1. import telemetry {
   prefix tm;
   }
2. import     telemetry {
   prefix tm;
   }
3. import

   telemetry {
      prefix tm;
    }

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -Eq "import\s+telemetry"  "./xyz.yang";
    then
      echo "This is a telemetry yang"
    else
      echo "This is a normal yang"
fi
```

The above works for 1 and 2 but not for 3.

I tried following but it's greedy and will match "import blah blah blah.. telemetry " as well.

```
if awk '/import/,/telemetry/' "./xyz.yang";
```

Any suggestions?

**My solution:**

```
#!/bin/sh
    if grep -Pzq 'import[ \n\r\t]+telemetry' './xyz.yang';
        then
          echo "This is a telemetry yang"
        else
          echo "This is a normal yang"
    fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a `-z` flag to grep and it will work.

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -Eqz "import\s+telemetry"  "./xyz.yang";
    then
      echo "This is a telemetry yang"
    else
      echo "This is a normal yang"
fi
```